# Nextjs - getServerSideProps not working on server

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to get data of detail post and set it to meta tag.

It’s working fine on localhost with script `dev` and `start`, but when I upload the code to the EC2 server, I cannot getting this data from the API. I can't understand why it’s not working on the server.

Here is file [slug].jsx:

```
export default function PostDetail({ postDetail }) {
   return (
     <>
      <Head>
       <title>Post detail</title>
       <meta
        property="title"
        content={postDetail.title}
       />
       <meta
        property="image"
        content={postDetail.banner.url}
       />
       <meta
        property="description"
        content={postDetail.description}
       />
      </Head>
      <div>...</>
     </>
   )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
    try {
        const res = await api.postApi.getBySlug(query.slug);
        
        return { props: { postDetail: res.data } };
    } catch (err) {
        return { props: {} };
    }
};
```

Here is my script of package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3001",
    "export": "next export"
},
```

Thank you for reading and your help

Comment: "I cannot getting this data from the API" - Can you be more specific? Do you get any errors? Can you add the code for `api.postApi.getBySlug`?

Comment: I cannot get any error, it looks like `getServerSideProps` is not called. I added the code for API and it working perfectly on localhost but it’s not working on the server. I tried to run code with env production on my pc and it's also working but on the server, it doesn't.